# How can I format the XML response - Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, unit-testing, response

I am trying to get some values from an XML response, but I am getting this error.

Why is json.loads not working?

What I did was convert response that was in byte to str.
Then then use loads to format the file to get the values.

Does anyone have another idea how I can format this response?

**raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

This is my code so far.

```
import json, requests, urllib.parse, re
from termcolor import colored
import numpy as np
import sqlite3, math, jmespath, os
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict

# Set Up
dateinplay = "2021-11-29"
cdwenv1 = "cdwu"  # Note that it only works with the http version right now

emberEndPoint = "http://emberu:8084/ember/v2/hierarchy/" 
tempdir = r"J:\E2E Testing Service\2.- Improvement\ALP Project"
dbname = f"{tempdir}\\ALP.sqlite"
batchsize = 3000

conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)

# Dev Static
cdwenv = ""  # leave empty


# Create a list of all books from Ember
emberRaw = requests.get(emberEndPoint + dateinplay).text
ember_str = str(emberRaw).encode("cp850", "replace").decode("cp850")
emberJsonObj = json.loads(ember_str)
# print(emberJsonObj)
```

XML response:

```
<cmfHierarchy reportingDateTime="2021-12-20T03:04:39.028+00:00" asOfDate="2021-11-29+00:00">
  <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="2" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="1900-01-01Z" status="Active" categoryName="Legal Entity" categoryCode="LE" name="Mizuho Securities Group" code="MHSC" id="LE0MHSC">
    <identifiers>
      <identifier value="2278" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
    </identifiers>
    <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="3" parentCategoryName="Legal Entity" parentCode="MHSC" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="1900-01-01Z" parent="LE0MHSC" status="Active" categoryName="Legal Entity" categoryCode="LE" name="MSUK Holdings Group" code="MSUKG" id="LEMSUKG">
      <identifiers>
        <identifier value="2291" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
      </identifiers>
      <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="8690" parentCategoryName="Legal Entity" parentCode="MSUKG" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="2009-12-01Z" oracleCode="72701" parent="LEMSUKG" status="Active" categoryName="Legal Entity" categoryCode="LE" name="Mizuho International" code="MHI" id="LE00MHI">
        <identifiers>
          <identifier value="2059" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
        </identifiers>
        <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="6995" parentCategoryName="Legal Entity" parentCode="MHI" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="2011-04-01Z" parent="LE00MHI" status="Active" categoryName="Division" categoryCode="DV" name="Central" code="00021" id="DV00021">
          <identifiers>
            <identifier value="2706" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
          </identifiers>
          <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="6996" parentCategoryName="Division" parentCode="00021" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="2011-04-01Z" parent="DV00021" status="Active" categoryName="Business" categoryCode="BU" name="Central" code="00184" id="BU00184">
            <identifiers>
              <identifier value="2707" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
            </identifiers>
            <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="6997" parentCategoryName="Business" parentCode="00184" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="2011-04-01Z" parent="BU00184" status="Active" categoryName="Department" categoryCode="DP" name="Central" code="00174" id="DP00174">
              <identifiers>
                <identifier value="2708" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
              </identifiers>
              <unit unitValidToDate="9999-12-31Z" unitValidFromDate="2019-10-30Z" orderBy="7068" parentCategoryName="Department" parentCode="00174" unitEndDate="9999-12-31Z" unitStartDate="2011-04-01Z" oracleCode="STR-0134" parent="DP00174" status="Active" categoryName="Cost Centre" categoryCode="CC" name="International Dept" code="0134" id="CC00134">
                <identifiers>
                  <identifier value="2709" name="UnitId" system="MiCore"></identifier>
                </identifiers>
              </unit>
            </unit>
          </unit>
        </unit>
```

Comment: the b'' indicates that it's a byte string. You can .encode() this to create utf-8

Answer (score 1):

The `'b'` in front of the XML is an indicator that the data type of what you're printing is a byte array (not a string).

If you want to pretty print your XML you can parse it with an XML parser and then pretty print it like this:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
from io import BytesIO
fp = BytesIO(emberObj)
x = etree.parse(fp)
print(etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True))
```